# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'Symbol'

Tags: typeerror

I get this TypeError

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'Symbol'".
```

Apparently it occurs in the second part where I subtract an entry of the list and the symbol for the solver (T_sto[t,l-1]-x). But I do not subtract the whole list but only an entry, so I don't get why it fails to run. Can anybody help? I'm sure it's an easy problem but I'm still struggling with it for days now.

Here is my code:

```
for t in range(1, n_H):
for l in range(layers):

        if (t==1): # use T_init(i) instead of T(t-1, i)
            if(l>0):
                T_prev=T_init[l-1]
        else:
                T_prev=T_sto[t-1,l]

        if (l==1): # Top layer 
                T_sto[t,l] = solve((m_sto[l-1]*c_w/dt * (x - T_prev) - m_hp[t] * c_w * sheet.cell_value(t,8)
                                + m_hou[t] * c_w * x + m_hou[t] * c_w * T_sto[t,l+1] 
                                + m_hp[t] * c_w * x
                                + k_sto * A_sto[l-1] * (x - T_sur) 
                                - lbd * A_CS / dz[l-1] * (T_sto[t,l+1] - x)), x)


        elif (l==2): # Medium layer has the heat generator
                T_sto[t,l] = solve(m_sto[l-1]*c_w/dt * (x - T_prev) - m_hou[t] * c_w * (T_sto[t,l+1] - x)                                    
                                - m_hp[t] * c_w * (T_sto[t,l-1] - x)
                                + k_sto * A_sto[l-1] * (x - T_sur)
                                - lbd * A_CS / dz[l-1] * (T_sto[t,l+1] - 2*x + T_sto[t,l-1]), x)
```

Comment: It might help those interested in specific languages if you add appropriate language tag to your question.